# Why ablative "corporibus" and "funeribus" are used in this excerpt from Tacitus "Annals" XVI?

Tags: syntax, grammar-identification, ablative, tacitus

In Tacitus *Annals* XVI, 13, one can [read](https://books.openedition.org/obp/1350) (emphasis mine on the words that cause me difficulty):

> Vastata Campania turbine ventorum, qui villas arbusta fruges passim disiecit pertulitque violentiam ad vicina urbi; in qua omne mortalium genus vis pestilentiae depopulabatur, nulla caeli intemperie quae occurreret oculis. Sed domus **corporibus** exanimis, itinera **funeribus** complebantur; non sexus, non aetas periculo vacua; servitia perinde et ingenua plebes raptim extingui, inter coniugum et liberorum lamenta, qui dum adsident, dum deflent, saepe eodem rogo cremabantur.

There is a translation to English of the text in the above link, so I can understand its meaning. But I cannot see why the ablative *corporibus* and *funeribus* are used. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: It is a type of [instrumental ablative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ablative_(Latin)#Instrumental_ablative), possibly ablative of agent, though I'm not confident enough to classify it and write an answer. Houses were filled _with_ bodies and streets _with_ (by?) funerals. In that case you can use ablative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're formed with the verb **complebantur**, which [is accompanied](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcompleo) by an **ablative of material**.

The translation makes it clear:

> But the houses were filled *with lifeless bodies* (*corporibus exanimis*), the streets *with funerals* (*funeribus*).

You can read more on the ablative of material in [Allen and Greenough §403](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/ablative-source-and-material):

> The ablative (usually with a preposition) is used to denote the source from which anything is derived, or the Material of which it consists.

Comment: A&G class this as ablative of means: 409a. I had a professor who insisted on “ablative of content” since what something is filled with is logically distinct from the means of filling.

Comment: @Kingshorsey Yeah, I disagree with means and agree with your professor that material/content (same basic idea) is more likely here, as Lewis and Short state.

Comment: As an addendum, it seems to me that ablative of means would be the way in which the material filled in location, not the material/content itself.

Comment: That's why "content" is better than both material and means. If I fill a metal bucket with water using a hose, I have metal as the bucket material, water as the content, and hose as the means.

Comment: Also, I don't really care much about how we label it, but your answer points to the wrong section in A&G. Verbs of filling are discussed in 409a.