# Usage of ablative in a sentence by Curtius

Tags: syntax, grammar-identification, genitive, ablative

This text comes from Quintus Curtius Rufus *Historiae Alexandri Magni*, book 3, chapter 5 (emphasis mine):

> Mediam Cydnus amnis, de quo paulo ante dictum est, interfluit. Et tunc aestas erat, cuius calor non aliam magis quam Ciliciae oram vapore solis accendit, et diei fervidissimum tempus esse coeperat. **Pulvere** simul ac **sudore** perfusum regem invitavit liquor fluminis, ut calidum adhuc corpus ablueret; itaque, veste deposita, in conspectu agminis — decorum quoque futurum ratus, si ostendisset suis levi ac parabili cultu corporis se esse contentum — descendit in flumen.

I've read a translation to Catalan of the particular sentence where *pulvere* and *sudore* appear, so its meaning is not a problem for me.
The translation in Catalan of the expression *pulvere simul ac sudore perfusum* is "cobert de pols i ensems de suor". In Spanish would be "cubierto a la vez de polvo y de sudor" and in Italian "coperto contemporaneamente di polvere e di sudore". Such translations to some Romance languages lead me to think that the genitive should be used for the words in boldface in the text.
A similar construction in which genitive is used, that I found in the book *Método de Latín II: Incorpora Clave y Vocabulario Latino* by Santiago Segura Munguía, is

> Auri amore scelus commissit.

I cannot understand why the author uses the ablative case for such words.

Comment: It's the exact same situation as in [your previous question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/23120/why-ablative-corporibus-and-funeribus-are-used-in-this-excerpt-from-tacitus).

Comment: @Cairnarvon: So it's also an ablative of material?

Comment: @Charo, did you understand *pulvere* and *sudore* goes with *perfusum*? How would you render this in English?

Comment: @d_e: Yes, I understand that *pulvere* and *sudore* goes with *perfusum*. The translation in Catalan is "cobert de pols i ensems de suor". In Spanish would be "cubierto a la vez de polvo y de sudor" and in Italian "coperto contemporaneamente di polvere e di sudore". I'm not sure in English, I believe it may be something like "covered at the same time with dust and sweat".

Comment: Should I improve something in this question?

Comment: @Charo, perhaps some users thought that yes the question could be improved by providing additional details as to why the *genitive* is to be expected. Did you encountered some other examples with genitive for similar verbs, etc. Or it might be that some users thought another question is too close to this one -- this, however, is inherently harsh requirement for the asker as sometimes we just don't know that (or what) we don't know - in order to see a connection between question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Generally*, If the nouns in question answer questions like *in what manner*, *how*, *with what*, those nouns should appear in the ablative. this is pretty much a book-case for the ablative here. so an ablative -- to my mind at least -- is the most natural choice.

The genitive *usually* implies a possession and answers questions such as: *of what (whose)* or *which* or sometimes *from what*.

But indeed Some languages might be using a "possessive" preposition for an ablative in other languages; or more severely accusative for dative or vice versa. (Note, that in English at least the preposition *with* that you chose conforms to an ablative). There is not much we can do about this: and we should look up the dictionary to see the usages.

Having said all that, to assume a *genitive* in our example from Curtius would not be too far-fetched. There are verbs/adjective (few that is) that *also* work with the genitive. One of them is *impleo* (and perhaps its family) or the adjective *plenus*: we can say *plenus sacculus est aranearum* but we could also say *araneis*. Is *perfundo* such a rare verb? A good dictionary should have the answer.

Comment: I see, @d_e: unfortunately, any of my dictionaries don't specify which case is used with the verb *perfundo*.

Comment: @Charo Some dictionary authors do not specify this explicitly, but through the examples they list, such as [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dperfundo), who say: *To scatter or sprinkle over, to besprinkle, bestrew (poet.): “canitiem immundo perfusam pulvere turpans,” Verg. A. 12, 611: “sanguine currum,” Verg. A. 11, 88: “penates sanguine,” Ov. M. 5, 155* etc.

Answer (score 0):

*Sudore* and *pulvere* are ablatives of (inanimate) agent related to *perfusum*, the perfect participle of "perfundere" (transitive), so it has passive meaning.

Comment: In which sense are these ablatives of cause?

Comment: Sorry I meant ablative of (inanimate) agent (in my language, italian, it is called "efficient cause") and it is the agent of the passive meaning of profusus: "covered by dust and sweat". In other languages including mine, "covered with dust and sweat" or "covered of dust and sweat" would make more sense as translation (not in English probably.

Comment: Here https://quintushoratiusflaccus.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/od-i-5-la-tempesta-pirra-e-passata/, you can find "perfusus liquidis odoribus" and the explanation that "liquidis odoribus" is an abaltive of agent ("causa efficiente" in the explanation).

Comment: How do you explain *auro tecta perfudimus* (Sen. Ep. 115 (lib. XIX))?

Comment: I would consider it as ablative of means (instrumental) as ablative of material would need a preposition. "we cover (or we covered) the roofs with gold (using gold)"

Comment: @Davide Surely this analysis would also apply in the passive: *tecta (a Seneca) auro perfusa*. And also in the Curtius sentence. Gold is not the agent here, and neither are dust and sweat.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I see your point, although I still believe that an ablative of agent could be an option in general with a passive form.

Comment: An ablative of agent requires the preposition *a/ab*. That's a defining feature of the ablative of agent.

Comment: If the agent is an inanimate object, the preposition is not necessary. This is what I knew and studied at school and what I found here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ablative_(Latin)). I understand from your comments that this distinction is wrong and that is an instrumental ablative. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Davide I believe all the "ablative of such-and-such" titles (there are many) are a bit of a language game. I hadn't heard the name "ablative of material" until now. My point was only that there could be an agent in addition to the material in this case.